# change Usestate Object with prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am trying to change the value of items in the `selectedItems` Object, but the `changeSelectedItems` function always sets the name of the variable to type instead of the value of the property 'type'.
How do i use the type property as the name for the value?

```
const [selectedItems, SetselectedItems] = useState({
  shirt:'none',
  pants:'none',
  hat:'none',
})

const changeSelectedItems = (name,type) =>{
  SetselectedItems({type:name})
}

<div onClick={() =>changeSelectedItems('blue shirt','shirt')}> blue shirt </div>
<div onClick={() =>changeSelectedItems('jeans','pants')}> jeans </div>
<div onClick={() =>changeSelectedItems('tophat','hat')}> tophat </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be

```
  const [selectedItems, SetselectedItems] = useState({
    shirt:'none',
    pants:'none',
    hat:'none',
  })

  const changeSelectedItems = (name,type) =>{
    SetselectedItems(selected => ({...selected, [type]:name}))
  }

<div onClick={() =>changeSelectedItems('blue shirt','shirt')}> blue shirt </div>
<div onClick={() =>changeSelectedItems('jeans','pants')}> jeans </div>
<div onClick={() =>changeSelectedItems('tophat','hat')}> tophat </div>
```

Comment: You're still dumping code in your answers without explaining/documenting what you've done.

Answer (score 2):

Just go:

```
 const changeSelectedItems = (name,type) =>{
    SetselectedItems({...selectedItems, [type]: name })
  }
```

Here's some info about the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) I've used and you can read more about computed properties in [this article](https://attacomsian.com/blog/javascript-computed-property-names#:%7E:text=The%20computed%20property%20names%20feature,key%2Dvalue%20pairs%20called%20properties.).

Comment: Maybe include some documentation for the spread syntax, explain what that means, and maybe link to an article that explains what a "computed property name" is.

Comment: Added some references, thanks Andy.

Comment: Nice. And it makes your answer much better than the accepted one. SO is an odd site because it a) the gamification (badges, upvotes) encourages you to answer early but also b) wants to be a repository of really great documented answers. I'm old-hat now and tend to take my time on answers that I think will benefit the site. Do I get the upvotes? Sometimes. But that's not what's important to me. Anyway, nice work. Keep it up.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change the state of a specific key do it like this

```
SetselectedItems(oldState => ({...oldState, [type]:name}))
```

the spread operator `...` get all object without what specific key  you put the value

Comment: Maybe explain spread syntax? The OP might not know what that is.

Comment: @Andy I added small explain about spread operator